# How did the main character of Don't Breathe lose his sight?

Tags: dont-breathe

How did the main character of *[Don't Breathe (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4160708/)* lose his sight?

I was trying to google the plot and reading it through, but still did not find an answer to my question. I was hoping that someone here might know it.

Comment: Don't Breathe 2 has been out for at least a month now. Might wanna check that out as it might answer your question.

Comment: If it isn't made clear anywhere it's likely intentional.

Comment: @JMERICKS, it does not answer my question. I saw the second movie. That is when I decided to post this question - after watching it. :)

Comment: Does that have any importance to the plot of either movies? I watched the first one, it doesn't make any difference to the story being told: blind man's house robbery gone wrong. If it does have any relevance in the second movie, please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Luciano, in reality nothing has any relevance even the movie itself. It is just an entertainment. But in this particular case I am no more than just interested to know the main character better. Who knows, maybe it would change something in my perception of his actions and decisions or the movie as a whole. Also, if it was mentioned in movie somewhere and would be posted here as an answer, then it would be a useful reprimand to my attention and research skills. :)

Comment: @Luciano, `I watched the first one, it doesn't make any difference to the story being told: blind man's house robbery gone wrong.` that is a wrong attitude imho. I think it is correct to say that it does not make any difference to the story only after you know it (i.e. the reason he is blind).

Comment: I think you got me wrong: some details are omitted because it's just not important enough to the movie plot. If you're asking a question you should explain why is this important to the understanding of the movie, otherwise it's just mere curiosity or trivia.